# Comparison of Fixnum with nil failed - palindrome program Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, null, palindrome, fixnum

I was working on a program for question 4 in Project Euler - find the largest palindrome among multiples of 3-digit numbers.  This is what I wrote:

```
def palintest(number)
    num = number.to_s
    len = num.length

    if len  % 2 != 0
        num[(len/2).floor] = ''
    end

    if num[0.. (len/2)-1] == num [len/2..len].reverse!
        return number
    end
end

palindromes = []

for i in 100..999
    for j in 100..999
        palindromes << palintest(i*j)
    end
end

puts palindromes.max
```

I got an error that says:

```
comparison of Fixnum with nil failed
(repl):24:in `each'
(repl):24:in `max'
(repl):24:in `initialize'
```

I can't really figure out what's going on, I've tested each component of the program and it seems to be in working order.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of nils that you are adding to your array. Max can't work with nils - it compares each element. Just add `palindromes << palintest(i*j) if palintest(i*j)`

But really might read better like:

```
def palindrome?(number)
    num = number.to_s
    len = num.length

    num[(len/2).floor] = '' unless len.even?        

    num[0..(len/2)-1] == num[len/2..len].reverse # return boolean
end

palindromes = []

for i in 100..999
    for j in 100..999
        palindromes << (i * j) if palindrome?(i * j)
    end
end

puts palindromes.max
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful!  I'm just starting out so I do overlook a lot of simple things.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, this happens because when  i*j is not a palindrome, palintest(i*j) returns nil.

Quick fix :

```
puts palindromes.reject(&:nil?).max
```